# Can you implement a stacked ActionBar on a tablet?

Tags: android-actionbar, android

I have implemented an ActionBar with my own custom icons. I have added tabs as well but I want these to appear below the ActionBar. At the moment they are displaying in the ActionBar. According to the Android Developers guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

> when the screen is wide enough the tabs appear in the action bar
>   alongside the action buttons (such as when on a tablet, shown in
>   figure 7), while when on a narrow screen they appear in a separate bar
>   (known as the "stacked action bar", shown in figure 8)

Is it possible to implement a stacked action bar permanently so that the tabs are constantly displayed below the ActionBar across all devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same effect as in that image, you can use tabs. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) is a tutorial on how to implement them.

Comment: No this displays the tabs in the ActionBar. As mentioned above I want them below the ActionBar.